# Find all non-NUL bytes in a file

Tags: files, grep

I am zeroing media with simple `pv /dev/zero > ...` and want to know if after this command there is any other byte on the media. This would allow me to know that media is corrupted. I assume ideal environment that any other process will not write to the media in the meantime.

I've tried command `grep -vP '\x00' ...` but it does not give any feedback in both cases: 1. file has only NUL bytes 2. file has other bytes. Eventually I add `; echo $?` but it always gives 0.

Am I missing something? What is the proper command to check?

Comment: What is it what you call _media_? A file?

Comment: A block device like /dev/sda.

Comment: You're missing a couple of things (1) `grep` is line-based, it's not going to work well on binary data (2) in any case `grep -vP '\x00'` would match *lines* that *do not contain* null bytes (which is not the same as lines that contain non-null bytes)

Comment: @steeldriver ok, so what would be the solution in bash to achieve what I need?

Comment: If I knew that I'd post an answer ;)

Comment: Maybe a simple solution in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -qP '[^\x00]' ...; echo $?
```

The `-q` flag tells grep to return 0 as soon as it sees a non-null byte (`[^\x00]`). Otherwise it returns 1. This gives a speed benefit for positive matches.

For example, reading 100 million random bytes, then 100 million zero bytes:

```
$ time head -c 100000000 /dev/urandom | grep -qP '[^\x00]'; echo $?

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
0
$ time head -c 100000000 /dev/zero | grep -qP '[^\x00]'; echo $?

real    0m4.281s
user    0m4.120s
sys     0m0.268s
1
```

Comment: `pv file | grep -qP '[^\x00]' ; echo $?` for progress for big files/devices.